# How to retrieve the HD vendor/serial using Windows API

Tags: c++, c, windows

I'm talking about the **physical** disk drive, not volume/partition/logical drive. So that usually-suggested `GetVolumeInformation` function is not applicable in my case.

To be exact: I'm working directly with the disk which has not been partitioned yet.
I open a handle to it via `CreateFile` function:

```
hDisk = CreateFile(
    _T("\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0"),
    GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED|FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
    NULL);
```

I can read/write directly on the disk using this handle. There's also a possibility to query various disk properties using `DeviceIoControl` function. However I couldn't find a way to query the disk vendor/serial properties, which are visible in the device manager.

Comment: Just guessing: do you want this to create some sort of licensing system ?

Comment: Use WMI, Win32_DiskDrive class

Comment: ereOn: No, I'm building a stresstesting tool for HD drives.

Comment: @ereOn: Just out curiosity, wouldn't you recomend this?

Comment: @TheMask: For a licensing system ? No. Changing a disk is something that can happen several times in a computer's lifetime. Invalidating a software license because of a disk change seems a bit excessive. Now one could rely on several other elements to determine that license is invalidated.

Comment: @ereOn: Interesting... which elements, for example? (just out curiosity, I'm not building a licensing system...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [DiskId32](http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/diskid32.html). Source code is there also. The idea is to use `DFP_RECEIVE_DRIVE_DATA` with `DeviceIoControl`.